# Redis Compile Error

Tags: ubuntu, redis

I'm trying to install redis 2.2.5 on Ubuntu 11.10. Running `make` gives me the following error:

```
cc -o redis-server -std=c99 -pedantic -O2 -Wall -W   -lm -pthread   -g -rdynamic -ggdb     adlist.o ae.o anet.o dict.o redis.o sds.o zmalloc.o lzf_c.o lzf_d.o pqsort.o zipmap.o sha1.o ziplist.o release.o networking.o util.o object.o db.o replication.o rdb.o t_string.o t_list.o t_set.o t_zset.o t_hash.o config.o aof.o vm.o pubsub.o multi.o debug.o sort.o intset.o syncio.o
vm.o: In function `computeObjectSwappability':
/home/prakhar/redis-2.2.5/src/vm.c:446: undefined reference to `log'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [redis-server] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/prakhar/redis-2.2.5/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

'log' here is a function name, used to figure out logarithm.

I guess this error is because the linker can't find the libm.a (i.e. the math library where 'log' function resides in).

You'd better to check if a math library exists on your system

Answer (score 0):

Try executing

> make distclean

i had the error: `"jemalloc/jemalloc.h: No such file or directory"`
maybe it comes from the same family

also, some packages are missing on Ubuntu sometimes. Try installing

> sudo apt-get -y install build-essential

Hope this helps